# 3d big-bang not working

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying following simple code from https://docs.racket-lang.org/pict3d/universe.html :

```
#lang racket
(require pict3d
         pict3d/universe)
(big-bang3d 0)
```

However, on running it, DrRacket crashes and closes. On running from a script file in Linux, it produces a black window which sticks and has to be killed. The console shows following error:

```
$ ./simple_bigbang.rkt
XSetErrorHandler: given value does not fit primitive C type
  C type: _fpointer
  given value: #<procedure:flag-x-error-handler>
  context...:
   /usr/share/racket/pkgs/gui-lib/mred/private/wx/gtk/gl-context.rkt:292:5
   /usr/share/racket/pkgs/gui-lib/mred/private/wx/gtk/gl-context.rkt:276:0: glx-create-context-attribs
   /usr/share/racket/pkgs/gui-lib/mred/private/wx/gtk/gl-context.rkt:319:4: for-loop
   /usr/share/racket/pkgs/gui-lib/mred/private/wx/gtk/gl-context.rkt:318:2
```

I am running DrRacket version 6.3 under Linux Mint.

Where is the problem and how can I correct it.

### Edit:

I installed latest version 6.8 from http://download.racket-lang.org/ and tried again. An empty window opnes but following is the error:

```
.racket/6.8/pkgs/pict3d/pict3d/private/gl/framebuffer.rkt:89:0: check-gl-framebuffer-status: The framebuffer does not have at least one image attached to it.
```

I tried a more complex version from https://docs.racket-lang.org/pict3d/universe.html :

```
#lang racket

(require pict3d
         pict3d/universe)

(current-material (material #:ambient 0.01
                            #:diffuse 0.39
                            #:specular 0.6
                            #:roughness 0.2))

(define lights+camera
  (combine (light (pos 0 1 2) (emitted "Thistle"))
           (light (pos 0 -1 -2) (emitted "PowderBlue"))
           (basis 'camera (point-at (pos 1 1 0) origin))))

(define (on-draw s n t)
  (combine (rotate-z (rotate-y (rotate-x (cube origin 1/2)
                                         (/ t 11))
                               (/ t 13))
                     (/ t 17))
           lights+camera))

(big-bang3d 0 #:on-draw on-draw)
```

Again, an empty window opens with following error:

```
.racket/6.8/pkgs/pict3d/pict3d/private/gl/framebuffer.rkt:89:0: check-gl-framebuffer-status: The framebuffer does not have at least one image attached to it.
```

Comment: You should raise an issue on the [pict3d github repository](https://github.com/jeapostrophe/pict3d)

Comment: Pl see my edit above.

Comment: If `pict3d` isn't working in Racket 6.8 under Linux Mint, you should raise an issue about it on the `pict3d` github repository

Answer (score 2):

> I am running DrRacket version 6.3 under Linux Mint.

First things first. Install a new version of Racket to make sure the bug is not already fixed.

If at all possible use a version from:

```
http://download.racket-lang.org/
```

Comment: Time to fill in a bug report. It might be something to do with the type of graphics "card" in your computer.

Comment: I am using Nvidia card with nouveau driver.

Comment: Is that a third party driver? Does it work with NVidea drivers?

Comment: Nouveau is Accelerated Open Source driver for nVidia cards: https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/ . I have not tried with Nvidia proprietary driver.